# How to encrypt data before insert/update and decrypt before select from mysql table?

Tags: mysql, sql, encryption, cryptography, password-encryption

I have 80 tables in a MySQL DB and I want to encrypt data of these table so that no one can access data directly.

1) The no. of queries in my project is too high so I can't use AES_ENCRYPT(column_name, key) for encryption and AES_DECRYPT(column_name, key) for decryption of data in each query.

2) I can use Data Encryption at Rest but it only encrypts db files (*.ibd ). However, data is still in normal form and any user can see the real data from any workbench (MySQL Workbench, Sqlyog or command line).

Is there any other way by which I can encrypt and decrypt MySQL data? Or any other db that provides functionality to store data in an encrypted form?

I am using MySQL version 5.7.23

Comment: Tag properly!!!  If this is MySQL, why do I see `SQL Server` tag in your question???  They are completely different products.

Comment: You need to consult a security professional to advise you on how to approach this as what you're suggesting here is just a layer of obfuscation, it's not actually making your data more secure. Your database is an asset that should as secure as possible, with maximal security settings and a minimal number of people should have direct access. No amount of AES can make a loosely secured server magically secure. If you can't lock down your database, you won't secure your keys properly either, so this is all just theatre with zero increase in actual security.

Comment: If you encrypt the actual database values your indexes are useless and your database turns into nothing but binary goo which is extremely unpleasant to work with. Encrypt at rest, encrypt your backups, and have extremely restrictive access, grant only what is strictly necessary.

Comment: Good security means that encryption key need to change regularly. How will you handle table that has data encrypted with different keys?

Answer (score 1):

1) If the cost for encryption/decryption using the db is to high on the query level then there is no much you can do to reduce costs, besides not using encryption.

2) I don't get this. If you are concerned about users accessing data they are not supposed to access, what about restricting user access to the data on a per table level [1]? If some users need access to some portions of the data, you could use views, only exposing those portions.

[1] https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privilege-system.html